# Ler appSettings Web.config encriptado

Tags: asp

Em uma aplicação que utiliza asp clássico, tenho uma key chamada `connection:asp30` e outra chamada `connection:asp60`. 
Essa aplicação possuí diversas páginas asp e outras aspx.

Encriptei o Web.config a pedido de um cliente, utilize:

> aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "appSettings" "D:\Users\rafael.barbosa\Desktop\Aplicacao - 5.0" –prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"

Ok.

As conexões dos .asp utilizam o `connection:asp30` e as conexões do .aspx utilizam o `connection:asp60`

Ao criptografar, as conexões do .aspx continuaram funcionando regularmente, porem, os .asp pararam de funcionar.

A conexão do .asp funciona da seguinte forma:

```
  strConexao = GetXmlProp("connection:asp30", "")
  gstrConn = strConexao

  Set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Set rstConf = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Set objConnection =  Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  objConnection.Open gstrConn
```

Sendo a função:

```
Function GetXmlProp(propName, stdvalue) Dim Node Dim cfgFile   Dim fso
      If IsEmpty(objXMLCfg) Or IsNull(objXMLCfg)  Then

    'determinar web.config
    cfgFile = Session("ApplicationRootPath") & "\web.config"

    Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not fso.FileExists(cfgFile) Then       Response.Write "Atenção: arquivo " & cfgFile & " não encontrado."     End If
        Set fso = Nothing

    Set objXMLCfg = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objXMLCfg.Async = False
    objXMLCfg.Load(cfgFile)   
           End If    
    Set Node = objXMLCfg.documentElement.selectSingleNode("/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='" & propName & "']")
     If Not Node Is Nothing Then
    GetXmlProp = Node.getAttribute("value")   Else
    GetXmlProp = stdvalue   End If
     End Function
```

O que posso fazer para que meu Web.config seja compreendido e a aplicação acesse o banco também na camada .asp ?

Comment: O meio mais seguro seria criar uma classe de banco de dados na sua aplicação para manipular o sql dela, lá você criaria regras,  poderia criar uma lista com suas conexões e via programação elas seriam acionadas.

Answer (score 3):

Uma vez encriptado o arquivo voce não consegue mais acessar essa seção "prov" pelo ASP.

Para resolver seu problema, e deixar seu cliente feliz, eu utilizaria algum Encriptador/Decriptador em ASP e colocaria a string de conexão criptografada em outra sessão no seu web.config (outro caminho diferente do "prov") que nao passasse pelo aspnet_regiis.

Ou seja, seu ASP usaria uma criptografia própria e sua string de conexão não estaria visível para alguem ler direto do arquivo web.config.

Se o cliente não gostar dessa solução, voce pode fazer o login pelo aspx, dar um redirect para um asp, passando essa connection string numa variável de sessão e usando no lado do ASP.